# Nmap compiled without nsock engine error

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

I'm using Nmap on bash shell, with Ubuntu on a Windows 10 machine( from windows developer tools), and installed Nmap.
However when I try to use it like so or with additional arguments:

```
nmap -v google.com
```

I get the following errors:
[image]

If I check the version with the -V option like so

```
nmap -V
```

I get the following at the bottom:

[image]

The issue seems to be with the compiling of the nsock engines.
I checked around the net and ubuntu's websites, however, could not find any solution.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the nsock engines. The "Compiled without:" line is empty, meaning that no features are unavailable. Instead, the problem is running a program that expects very specialized Linux networking functions to work, when Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) does not implement those functions. The WSL team is working on expanding support, but the level of control necessary to do what Nmap does will not be easy to implement.

The solution is to use the official [Nmap installer for Windows](https://nmap.org/download.html#windows). Nmap works great on Windows, with full support for all features.

Comment: Thanks, @bonsaiviking